# PHP code isn't submitting into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a login for a website. So far whenever I post to my database doesn't show the submitted information, the only things which are posted is a hashed password.

```
<form method="post" action="submit.php">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email">Email:</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="username">Username:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password">Password:</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="pwd2">Re-Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd2">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" class="form-control" id="submit">
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

To submit into this php block

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
   $password = "Password";
   $dbname = "DBNAME";


   $email = NULL;
   $user = NULL;
   $pass1 = NULL;

   if (isset($_POST['email'])){
   $email = $_POST['email'];
    }
   if (isset($_POST['username'])){
   $user = $_POST['username'];
   }

    if (isset($_POST['password'])){
   $pass1 = $_POST['password'];
   }
  $hash = password_hash($pass1, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);


   $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

   if ($conn->connect_error) {
   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
   } 

   $sql = "INSERT INTO Users (email, username, password )
   VALUES ('$email', '$user', '$hash')";

   if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
   echo "New record created successfully";
   } else {
   echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

  $conn->close();
  ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your form fields lack name attributes. Without them no values are sent your your script. This is easily testable by doing `var_export($_POST)`.

```
<form method="post" action="submit.php">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pwd2">Re-Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pwd2" id="pwd2">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" class="form-control" id="submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

FYI, you are wide open to [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174)

Comment: Thank you, it works, I'll start working on blocking SQL injections

Comment: Cool. You're off to a good start by using the new password functionality in PHP and using mysqli over mysql. Now you're ready to take it to the next level and prevent those darn sql injections.